# Access: How to structure input vs read only forms

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Ive got a peoples DB and after some development my recordset for the main form is not updatable because of subqueries etc etc..

All this is because i redesigned the DB to resemble real life more, meaning i added some tables that could track certain things. This made the relations a little more complex and now im left with a DB i cant add new records to or edit hahaha and thats pretty useless

So I'm left thinking it can't only be me so there is either a simple solution i can't see or i have designed my forms totally wrong.

**Whats the praxis in design/structure when you have/get a form based on a recordset that's not updatable in a "regular" peoples DB and you want to add or edit details in it?** (think HR managment DB)

[image: relationships]

*(Reason for the recordset being un-updatable: The recordset is based on a query that gets records from 3 related tables and does a MAX function on a date field to get the most recent record on two of the tables)*

Now i have a mainform and three subforms on it. I can edit/add info in the subforms of course but the mainForm displaying names and other personal details is not updatable...

The mainForms Query is querying the tblPerson, tblInmate, tblClassificationHistory and tblSquadHistory...

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would recommend two possibilities:

1. **Build an extra form** for input and edit data for persons where the only record source is tblPerson. This input/edit-form you can open in your main form via button or ribbon for example. You can build one form for input and edit data and change the behaviour by VBA-Code (or even Macros?). Or you can build two forms for edit and input data seperately. Also you can add OK and cancel buttons to safe or undo your changes. The possibilities are endless. This is basis ACCESS knowledge and there are tons of tutorials out there, so I will not explain this further.
2. **Change the query on the main form.**  If you have a continuous form and you do not want to add a new form, you should edit your query. I can not estimate your described query complexity with given information, but there must be a way to get the "MAX-date"-recordsset without aggregated ("Group By" -Statement) query results. Your goal is to change your main-form query, that it does not have any "Group by" part. Be aware that you can use subquerys to do the "Group by" for finding the "Max-Value". You should also check your main form query, if you really need all queried fields for the main form. Let your three subforms do the data query work.

Basically, the perfect user interface (UI) as forms in ACCESS depends on the users preferences, expectations and the use case itself. So you have to find out, which design suits best for your application. You can do some research on UI design patterns if you want get knowledge from recent experiences. It is a huge field of expertise!

Comment: Thank you for reaffirming what i kind already was thinking...I come form a UI based environment where most work started with UI and then you added programming (Flash) not sure if anyone remembers that "old" plugin :P I will look into the separate input/edit forms although that's seems a little backwards and UN-user-friendly you have fields there and you have to open something else to edit them..anyhow thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. I do not think this is the right place to discuss user-friendly and userunfriendly. As mentioned, it depends on the case. A separate form can be good if you want to prevent user from accidently changing a value in an overview list, but need more interact
Now to your query: Use qryMainTemp as your source for the form. Replace the Inner Join tables with your querys qrySquad and qryClassification. Add the fields you want to show to the qryMainTemp: Like `SELECT qryClassification.b.max_date` (I am not sure about naming from querys, do some research here...)That should do the trick.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look in to changing my queries. I spent the day trying to improve my more linear db version and it's not too bad now... I lack one option I have  in the new (above) structure... But almost all info I need is in one table... Got me thinking I shouldn't make it more complicated than it needs to be. So thanks again for your input. It's nice to bounce ideas and get advice like this. Im in a place where people don't even know what access is hahaha